# What's the exact significance of Android NDK platform version compared to API level?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I have an Android app with `minSdkVersion.apiLevel` set to 18 `targetSdkVersion.apiLevel` set to 23. Accordingly I set the NDK `platformVersion` to 18.

Unfortunately after adding OpenSSL to the mix, the JNI library now fails to link:

```
/Users/pol/Downloads/Cross/External/Android-Libraries/openssl-1.0.2g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'signal'
/Users/pol/Downloads/Cross/External/Android-Libraries/openssl-1.0.2g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
/Users/pol/Downloads/Cross/External/Android-Libraries/openssl-1.0.2g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
/Users/pol/Downloads/Cross/External/Android-Libraries/openssl-1.0.2g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'tcgetattr'
```

The problem goes away if setting `platformVersion` to 21 (it doesn't work either at 19).

What does this mean for the Android app if it has an API level of 18 but the JNI library was linked for 21? Will it crash at launch on a device running 4.3?

I cannot imagine the `signal` symbol be missing from 4.3 though. Is this an NDK bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what will happen to your shared library when you install it on android-20 or earlier: it will fail to load. You should not be surprised that `signal` was missing: Android runtime was never intended to run command-line tools like curl.

Comment: Actually do you know if it's possible to weak link these symbols so the JNI library does load on <21? I'm pretty sure they are not called at all, so it doesn't matter if they resolve to `null`.

Comment: I just built OpenSSL using the provided `./Configure android-armv7` to produce a static library, which then is merged into the JNI dynamic library, and everything works fine e.g. when using the OpenSSL hashing APIs. However, it's when I started to use `RAND_bytes()` that I got the linking errors above.

Comment: I realize this is better as a new question and asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129986/

Comment: If you use the [`setenv-android.sh`](https://wiki.openssl.org/images/7/70/Setenv-android.sh) instead, you will get OpenSSL for **_ANDROID_API** of your choice.

Comment: I did this experiment. For ANDROID_API=18 I got symbol **bsd_signal**; for ANDROID_API=21 there was **signal**.

Comment: I tried building using `Setenv-android.sh` on OS X, which succeeded, but when I try to use it in Android Studio, I get `Error:error: /.../openssl-1.0.2h/lib/libcrypto.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)`.

Comment: Note that I followed the wiki step by step. Is there any way to just use `./Configure android-armv7 && make -j && make install_sw` which is the simplest and works perfectly fine, but somehow provide the `ANDROID_API` target?

Comment: First of all, I could not build with setenv-android.sh on Mac without some tweaking. But then, I don't see problems linking in Android Studio a modified https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs sample that links to some ssl functions. If you share a minimal example, I could try to look at it more closely.

Comment: Thanks much for looking into this. At this point, I was able to use alternate method to replace that specific OpenSSL feature that was causing the original `signal()` and friends linking errors. I would really like to know if it's possible to specific an `ANDROID_API` target for `./Configure android-armv7`. That would be the easiest solution by far.

Comment: Actually, I realize I don't have a choice: I should really compile OpenSSL for API-18 since that's the minimum OS version required by the app. Any chances you could share your build script for OS X? Note that the app uses the static library of OpenSSL (which then gets linked into the JNI shared library), not the dynamic library.

Comment: Note that `setenv-android.sh` is not a replacement for `./configure`, it only sets the environment for `./configure`. That's why I cannot understand how you ended up with different results when you *just use ./Configure*

Comment: BTW to close the loop on this, I ended up switching to [mbedTLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) which is lightweight, pure C, compiles anywhere and is overall a gazillion times better than OpenSSL for my needs.

Comment: Worked for me when I set api to Android-21. Did not link on Android-20