# How to declare some symbols used by JNI shared library weak in Android Studio NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a JNI shared library built using the experimental Gradle NDK plug-in for Android Studio, and this library links to some OS library symbols that only exist after a specific Android version.

How to I define these specific symbols to be weak linked, or as a fallback, make the entire OS library containing them weak linked? The intent is that the JNI library doesn't fail to load on these older OSes and the symbols are just `null` at run time.

Concrete example: `signal()` in `libc` doesn't appear to be available pre-4.0.